# Android wear notification

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os

I want to create a notification, with list of options, but list has to be pretty long, lets say numbers from 1 to 60. I want to have a list like in a timer app, so I was thinking do I have to create a separate wear app for that, or is it possible to display that sort of notification from device only? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered under voice replies with predefined text responses.

[Voice Replies wearable documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/voice-input.html)
you can ignore the idea that is a voice reply.
this is the easiest option for using only the notifications without building an app specific for it.

Comment: Thank you. I will wait a bit longer and then accept answer